# REdirect In PHP w/ link info

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

Would it be possible to automatically redirect people from a page using PHP + the info that is introduced in the link?

I have a website [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and wish for users who visit [www.mywebsite.com/track/8182138](http://www.mywebsite.com/track/8182138)
to be redirected to [www.shippingcompany.com/shippingtracking/code/8182138](http://www.shippingcompany.com/shippingtracking/code/8182138)

Basically a redirect from my website [www.mywebsite.com/track/(codehere)](http://www.mywebsite.com/track/(codehere)) to the shipping company website tracking link.

I wish to do this because the shipping company tracking link is really really large, and we need to introduce the shipping into SMS messages. I am still taking my first steps with PHP, and already have some basic knowledge, so your insight into this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
\\Secure extracting numbers
$sen = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header('Location: www.shippingcompany.com/shippingtracking/code/' . $sen);
```

or

```
\\Secure extracting numbers
$sen = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header("Location: www.shippingcompany.com/shippingtracking/code/$sen");
```

or

```
\\split url by slash
$url= preg_split('/\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header('Location: www.shippingcompany.com/shippingtracking/code/' . array_pop($url));
```

or

```
\\split url by slash
$phone = array_pop(preg_split('/\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
header('Location: www.shippingcompany.com/shippingtracking/code/' . $phone);
```

I prefer first one because of security and performance balance

Comment: If it helps, let me know!